# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import 'tensorflow' in Python virtual environment

Tags: python, pip

I am facing an issue while trying to import the tensorflow module within a Python virtual environment. I followed the standard steps to set up a virtual environment and installed the required packages, but I keep encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import tensorflow.

I get the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I've verified that 'tensorflow' is installed within the virtual environment. When I run pip list or pip freeze, I can see 'tensorflow' listed along with its version number.

I'm puzzled as to why the module is not being found within the virtual environment despite it being installed. Am I missing any additional steps specific to using 'tensorflow' within a virtual environment?

Any suggestions or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Created a virtual environment using the command:

`python -m venv myenv`

- Activated the virtual environment:

On Windows:
 `.\myenv\Scripts\activate`

- Installed necessary packages using pip:

```
pip install numpy
pip install tensorflow
```

- Created a simple Python script named 'test.py' with the following content:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
```

- Executed the script using:
  `python test.py`

Comment: use `python -m pip install tensorflow` in activated virtualenv

Comment: Apparently, the `pip` command is not properly configured within the virtual env, and it installed the package in some other directory.

Comment: Show us the output of these commands `which pip` and `pip show tensorflow` (especially the `Location:` line), and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`